# Prove that these 3 points are in a straight line

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

$\triangle ABC$ is equilateral with a circle $\omega$ inscribed in it. MN is a tangent of $\omega$ and it intersects $AC$ and $BC$ at points $M$ and $N$ respectively. $AM_1=MC$ and $BN_1=CN$. $D,E,F$ touch the circle. $O$ is the center of $\omega$ and $OH_1 = r$. Prove that $M_1N_1$ intersects the center of $\omega$.

I've tried adding some additional segments (as you can see on the 2nd image). I've created $AR$ such that $AR=CN \Rightarrow MN=M_1R$ and $BP$ such that $BP=MC \Rightarrow PN_1=MN$. $\triangle CMN = \triangle AM_1R = \triangle BN_1P$. And if I want to prove that $M_1R$ and $N_1P$ touch $\omega$, I could say that it's because of symmetry (tell me if I'm wrong). That's all I've tried so far. Solving this problem would be equivalent to finding out that $M_1N_1$ bisects both the angle $\angle PN_1N$ and $\angle RM_1M$.

[image]

Comment: "Prove that $M_1N_1$ bisects the center of $\omega$." Do you mean, "Prove that $M_1N_1$ *contains* the center of $\omega$."? (The title of your question suggests so.)

Comment: Yes, does the sentence imply something else? It does cut the point. English isn't my native language, though.

Comment: Your English is good; there's just this one bit of vocabulary confusion. Usually, "bisects" means "divides into two equal pieces". I think you're using "bisects" where you mean "intersects", whose basic meaning is "meets". So, earlier in your question, you want to write that "$MN$ *intersects* $AC$ and $BC$ at $M$ and $N$." And then later, "Prove that $M_1N_1$ *intersects* the center of $\omega$."

Comment: You are so close, I really don't like to reveal the answer to keep its joy for you :-). And something else, I don't see a clear symmetry to say that those triangles are equal by symmetry.

Comment: *Hint:*

Try to prove $\angle M_1ON_1=180$

Comment: $$ \begin{cases} AM_1=CM\\ AR=CN\\ \angle A = \angle B = 60^{\circ} \end{cases} \Rightarrow \triangle M_1AR = \triangle MCN.$$
Similarly we can prove that all 3 of them are equal.
I only pointed out that we can prove the fact that $M_1R$ and $PN_1$ are tangent to $\omega$ by using symmetry. $BE$ and $AF$ would be the lines of symmetry.

Comment: Yes, It is right, and how do you prove $\triangle AM_1R = \triangle CMN$? (Of course they are congruent)

Comment: What do you mean? These are the exact same triangles I've just proved to be equal.

Comment: My mistake, forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I draw $M_1R$ **tangent** to $\omega$.

$M_1E=EM, OE=OE,E=90 \to \triangle OEM_1=\triangle OEM \\ \to \angle RM_1E =\angle NME = 2\angle OM_1E \to \angle RM_1A=\angle NMC \to \triangle ARM_1 = \triangle MNC$

$\angle EOF=360-\angle C - \angle E -\angle F = 120$, so to prove $\angle M_1ON_1=180$ we need to prove that $\angle EOM_1 + \angle FON_1=60$

$\angle RM_1E= \angle NME,\angle MNF= \angle PN_1F$

$\angle EMN + \angle FNM= 360-\angle FEC-\angle EFC= 240$

$\angle EOM_1 + \angle FON_1=90 - \angle OM_1E+90-\angle FN_1O = 180-\frac{\angle RM_1E+ \angle FN_1P}{2}\\=180-\frac{\angle EMN + \angle FNM}{2}=180-120=60 $

And this is what we wanted to prove.

[image]

Comment: Ohh, I've proved it. To solve the problem I can show that $\angle N_1OM=2\alpha$, where $\alpha = {1\over2}\angle M_1MN$. I also create a variable $\beta$ such that $2\beta=\angle MNN_1$. By knowing that angles of a quadrilateral add up to $360^{\circ}$, I can deduce that if $\angle N_1OM=2 \alpha$, then $$\alpha + 2\alpha +\beta +2\beta=360^{\circ}\Rightarrow 3\alpha + 3\beta = 360^{\circ}\Rightarrow \alpha + \beta=120^{\circ}$$ and that is if and only if $M_1, O$ and $N_1$ are in a straight line (because $\angle MON_1$ has to be equal to $2\alpha$ in order for the equality above to be true).

Comment: Dear @mathh , I am in a rush so I couldn't check your proof, but I updated my answer with a more complete version of my solution.

Comment: But we don't know yet that $\alpha+\beta=120^{\circ}$. We can find that out: $$\angle CM_1N_1+\angle CN_1M_1+\angle C=\alpha+\beta+60^{\circ}=180^{\circ} \Rightarrow \alpha+\beta=120^{\circ}$$
I've already said that this can only be true when $M1$, $O$ and $N1$ are in a straight line ⇒ they are indeed in a straight line.